# Firestore query returns empty snapshot when connection lost instead of Future. (Flutter web)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

(Everything works fine with internet connection)

When internet connection is disconnected it returns an empty `QuerySnapshot` instead of a `Future` with `ConnectionState.waiting`.

It also prints the error message to the console:

```
Cannot find native JavaScript type (firebase.FirebaseError) for type check
```

I tried the `.catchError(onError)` function or wrapping it inside a try-catch block but both can not detect the error.

```dart
fire.CollectionReference collectionReference =
        store.collection("collection");

    fire.QuerySnapshot questionsQuery = await collectionReference
        .where("person", "==", personID)
        .limit(30)
        .get();
```